# Python_How to reading multiple csv files and putting together in a file

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read multiple csv files from a folder and put together in a file.

But when I run my code below, each rows and columns and are combined in one box that are supposed to be separated.

Please let me know how to get right results.

## My Code

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

csv_folder = Path('D:/Myfolder')

def read_csv_with_retry(file_path, encodings):
 for encoding in encodings:
    try:
        return pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding=encoding, 
low_memory=False, error_bad_lines=False)
    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
        print(f"UnicodeDecodeError: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading {file_path} with encoding {encoding}: {e}")
raise Exception(f"Unable to read {file_path} with any of the specified encodings")

encodings_to_try = ['utf-8', 'cp949', 'latin1']

for file in csv_folder.glob('*.csv'):
 try:
    df = read_csv_with_retry(file, encodings_to_try)
 except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    continue

# Drop rows with missing values
df = df.dropna()

# Convert the entire DataFrame to string to handle mixed types
df = df.astype(str)

# Print some information about the data
print(f"Original file: {file}")
print(f"Number of rows before dropna: {len(df)}")
print("Sample of the data:")
print(df.head())

new_file_name = file.parent.joinpath(f"{file.stem}-edited.csv")

try:
    # Save the DataFrame with explicit encoding and line termination
    df.to_csv(new_file_name, index=None, encoding='utf-16', line_terminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error saving {new_file_name}: {e}")

print("Processing complete.")
```

Result:

[image]

Supposed to be:

[image]

Comment: Try to write your file with semi-colon as separator. `df.to_excel(..., sep=';')`. In fact, there are 2 questions: how to merge files in a single file and how to open it (them?) correctly in excel?

Answer (score 0):

You have to append your dataframes in a list then concat them:

```
dfs = []
for file in csv_folder.glob('*.csv'):
 try:
    df = read_csv_with_retry(file, encodings_to_try)
    dfs.append(df)
 except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    continue

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```

Maybe you should read [Import or export text (.txt or .csv) files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) to import your file correctly in Excel.